# Docker /usr/src/app path on Mac OS

Tags: macos, docker, path

I'm currently reading Deploying Rails with Docker, Kubernetes and ECS. In the book a Rails image from Dockerhub is use to create a new application. After running the following command a Rails application is created.

```
docker run -it --rm --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w / usr/src/app \
rails rails new --skip-bundle --api --database postgresql webapp
```

However, Docker needs this path `/usr/src/app` but this is only on Windows. In Mac OS the folder is `/usr/local/` should a `app` directory be created in `local` to follow along this path?

Answer (score 1):

What's inside docker is a totally separate thing from what's happening on your host system. You should leave this `"$PWD":/usr/src/app` as it is now, because the tutorial will certainly be based on that path.

**One word of a note concerning $PWD**

It's always easier to read and more consistent if you specify the path directly. 
Meaning if your project has a directory where all the rails app is setup, you are better off writing such a thing:

```
[..] -v ./ruby-app-directory:/usr/src/app [..]
```

or

```
[..] -v .:/usr/src/app [..]
```

for example:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v .:/usr/src/app -w / usr/src/app \
rails rails new --skip-bundle --api --database postgresql webapp
```

than leaving it to the variable.

**Example**

application tree:

```
root
  - one-app
    + some.sh
    + Dockerfile
  - second-app
    + some.rails
    + Dockerfile
```

With above application tree configuration you can use it like this:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v ./second-app:/usr/src/app -w / usr/src/app \
rails rails new --skip-bundle --api --database postgresql webapp
```

and everything that's inside `./second-app` will be placed inside the container in `/usr/src/app` location *(with /usr/src/app as a working directory set up by another argument)* so that the command you specify at the end of a `docker run` command, will be executed in `/usr/src/app` - the working directory.

Comment: But where would the rails `webapp` be located ? It generates a application in a path that doesn't exist.

Comment: Your app (Dockerfile etc) should be in the `second-app` or `one-app` 
 directory.